# Failure loading kernel module

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, modprobe

I've followed the steps at [Build Your Own Kernel Modules (CentOS)](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules#head-d2e4c05886f94c701e4ae74387d41d8c40c25d01) but when I modprobe it fails:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# modprobe pcnet32
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'pcnet32': Exec format error

[root@centos7 ~]# file /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/extra/pcnet32.ko
/lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/extra/pcnet32.ko: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=0xd7399934aef6f736c96175d7b91e570c49a86eda, not stripped
```

System info:

```
Linux centos7.testing 3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 6 21:12:36 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know what could be wrong :(

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you complied a 32-bit kernel module instead of a 64-bit kernel module?

Comment: I wonder if "make modules_prepare will not build a Module.symvers file even if the parameter CONFIG_MODULEVERSIONING has been set. Therefore a full kernel build will have to have been executed previously to make module versioning work." what's happening. I'm making a full build...

Comment: What steps did you follow very precisely? This may depend on your exact configuration. Copy-paste all the commands you ran. Where did you get the sources of the module? What headers did you use? Does anything appear in the kernel logs?

Comment: Well, I've solved doing something like that: